# Creating custom names for columns based on other column names in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns, naming

I have a dataframe like below:

[image]

I am looking to create a column using difference or use any other calculations among columns. However, I looking to name the column so that it relfects the operation done. For ex below I am finding the difference b/w Origin 1 and Dest 1 as below:

[image]

How do I create those custom naming of columns as highlighted and especially when I have to create multiple such columns.

Comment: @starball Sure, Thank you very much for your guidance. I will read through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through it and for naming you can use a f-string

```
for col_a in df.columns:
   for col_b in df.columns:
      if col_a != col_b:
         df[f'{col_a} - {col_b}'] = df[col_a] - df[col_b]
```

if you use itertools (pre-installed in python) you can make it easier to read (as proposed by @MustafaAydın):

```
import itertools
for col_a, col_b in itertools.permutations(df, 2):
    df[f'{col_a} - {col_b}'] = df[col_a] - df[col_b]
```

if you want to do multiple operations just add a line

```
import itertools
for col_a, col_b in itertools.permutations(df, 2):
    df[f'{col_a} - {col_b}'] = df[col_a] - df[col_b]
    df[f'{col_a} + {col_b}'] = df[col_a] + df[col_b]
```

if you only want to use subsets of columns, e.g. only from origin to destination you can do:

```
import itertools
origins = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Origin')]
destinations = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Dest')]
for col_a, col_b in itertools.product(origins, destinations):
    df[f'{col_a} - {col_b}'] = df[col_a] - df[col_b]
    df[f'{col_a} + {col_b}'] = df[col_a] + df[col_b]
```

Comment: So, if I have to create 10 such columns, I have to create 10 for loops? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: no, this will create all combination (all column pairs) with this one loop, or do you mean different operations like +, *, / ? if that is the case then you could simply add an additional row like this: `df[f'{col_a} + {col_b}'] = df['col_a'] + df['col_b']`

Comment: you need to remove quotes in RHS of last line. also, this calculates some extra unwanted columns. might want to cache df.columns.

Comment: Just add filtering for the operand ```if i != j and "-" not in j and "-" not in i:```

Comment: @Domagoj for readability, caching df.columns or itertools.permutations(df.columns, 2) is better IMHO. (what if an original column had "-" in it?)

Comment: @MustafaAydın I concur.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple.

Let's define a dataframe with two columns `a` and `b`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":[4,3,2,1]})
```

Output:

```
    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   3
2   3   2
3   4   1
```

Now, let's create the difference mentioned above between the two columns

```
df["a-b"] = df["a"] - df["b"]
```

Voila! Now you have a new column.

```
    a   b   a-b
0   1   4   -3
1   2   3   -1
2   3   2   1
3   4   1   3
```

For multiple iterative calculation, we can workout loop-based approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":[4,3,2,1],"c":[8,7,6,5]})

df["a-b"] = df["a"] -df["b"]

#if you want to calculate for every column combination
for i in df.columns:
    for j in df.columns:
        if i != j and "-" not in j and "-" not in i:
            df[f"{i}-{j}"] = df[i] - df[j]
```

This approach calculates all differences between all columns in one loop.

Output:

```
    a   b   c   a-b a-c b-a b-c c-a c-b
0   1   4   8   -3  -7  3   -4  7   4
1   2   3   7   -1  -5  1   -4  5   4
2   3   2   6   1   -3  -1  -4  3   4
3   4   1   5   3   -1  -3  -4  1   4
```

Comment: It will be very tiring to keep writing df["a-b"] for 100 such columns. Hence the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a for-loop approach and explanation. Although I do not like this 'nuke' approach. :)